# How to unpack 6 bytes as single integer using struct in Python

Tags: python, struct

I have the following 8 bytes:

```
b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00'
```

I'm trying to get two integers using struct.unpack: one for the first 2 bytes, and one for the last 6. Getting the first two is easy using:

```
struct.unpack("<H6B")
```

But, that returns

```
(5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0)
```

I want it to return the following:

```
(5, 5)
```

How do I get the integer value of the last 6 bytes? I do not want each byte individually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`struct`](https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) does not support integers with non-power-of-two size.  This is common.  C doesn't support such integers on your platform either (well, bitfields, but you can't make an array of those).

```
def unpack48(x):
    x1, x2, x3 = struct.unpack('<HHI', x)
    return x1, x2 | (x3 << 16)
```

Answer (score 6):

The standard struct module doesn't support all possible sizes so you either have to join some bits together yourself (see Dietrich's answer), or you can use external modules such as [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com).

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> b = BitArray(bytes=b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00')
>>> b.unpack('<H6B')
[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0]
```

which is the same as the standard `struct.unpack`. But now we can instead unpack the second item as a 6 byte (48 bit) little-endian unsigned integer:

```
>>> b.unpack('<H, uintle:48')
[5, 21474836480]
```

which gives you the same result as Dietrich's answer and also shows that you've got something the wrong way round in your question! What you need in this case is:

```
>>> b.unpack('uintle:48, <H')
[5, 5]
```

Note that you could also write `<H` as `uintle:16` if you wanted more consistent notation.